# Save As Copy from Data Driven Page in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 to Separate MXD per page in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: python, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am a beginner in ArcGIS and Python.

I have MXD document created in ArcGIS 10.5. I had created data driven page (DDP) using index shapefile consisted of 35 polygons. I had set name field in DDP from that shapefile with attribute information such as percil-1, percil-2,...percil-35.

I want to save new MXD with the name using the field name attribute but in previous version arcgis 10.0 or 10.1 not in 10.5 MXD version, and I want the final result something like this: percil-1.mxd, percil-2.mxd, percil-3.mxd....percil-35.mxd.

Can I do that in Python?

Comment: Have you tried simply using File|Save A Copy?  If so, what happened?

Comment: Are you asking how to create one 10.0 mxd for each data driven page?

Comment: I have tried using save as copy, but my driven page document contain 35 grid indexs in one thematic map. I have 7 thematic map to export. Now, I am using ArcGIS 10.5 but I am asked to save separate MXD in arcgis version 10.0

Comment: While possible, saving to an ancient format may result in data loss if the newer source was not supported. 10.0 has been in Retired status for 26+ months. At some point, conversion might result in an empty document.

Comment: It sounds like you need to [edit] more details into your question to describe more precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: So I have driven page MXD created in ArcGIS 10.5

Comment: So I have driven page MXD created in ArcGIS 10.5. This MXD contain of 35 pages if I export it multiple PDF. I create data driven page using index shapefile (35 polygon) and set name field from that shapefile with attribute name  percil-1, percil-2,...percil-35. So I want to Save new MXD with the name using field name but in previous version arcgis 10.0 not 10.5 MXD. and I hope the result something like this: percil-1.mxd, percil-2.mxd, percil-3.mxd....percil-35.mxd.

Comment: Please [edit] your question in response to our requests for clarifications. Potential answerers may not read long comment trails before deciding whether to move on to another question.

Comment: You will need to use ArcPy to do this and for help with that you need to start presenting some code to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck. I would cursor through the index layer.

Answer (score 3):

Use Mapping - MapDocumnet - saveACopy:

> This performs the same operation as File > SaveACopy in ArcMap

See first code sample (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    mxd.activeView = df.name
    mxd.title = df.name
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
del mxd
```

Add version to this line:

```
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\\" + df.name + ".mxd", '10.0')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, BERA. I will try your sugestion. But before that Can this script export all page (35 pages) in my driven page MXD?

Comment: That is what I asked you above. I dont understand your answer. The code will create on copy of one mxd. Data driven pages has nothing to do with making a copy of a MXD unless what you are asking is how to create one MXD for each data driven page?'

Comment: Yes, I want to create 10.0 seperate page MXD (35 pages in result) from one 10.5 driven page MXD using python script.

Comment: Copy one 10.5 MXD to one 10.0 MXD? The code will do this. The data driven pages is saved within the MXD.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion script above. But the result is only 1 mxd. Can you suggest, which part in the script above I must modify so the result will be each page with name from page name field of the index shapefile? I mean the result should be 35 MXDs.

Comment: Have a look at https://community.esri.com/thread/43201, that will give you the code to save each data driven page out to a separate MXD. `import arcpy  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Temp\GreatLakes.mxd")  
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages  
for pageNum in range(1, ddp.pageCount + 1):  
  ddp.currentPageID = pageNum  
  print "Saving %s.mxd" %(ddp.pageRow.getValue(ddp.pageNameField.name))  
  mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Temp\\" + ddp.pageRow.getValue(ddp.pageNameField.name) + ".mxd", "10.0")  
del mxd  `

Comment: Thank you Dan,,that script what I looking for. and work perpectly